# OpenTSDB and multiple values in a single measurement

Tags: opentsdb

As I understand it, OpenTSDB handles time series where the measument is a single value.  Many measurement devices deliver a set of values in a single measurements.  As an example this could be a single measurement for one device:  2012-12-16 01:00:00, temp=12, current=2, waterheight=3, nacl-level0.5, ....

Does OpenTSDB allow me to store these together or am I forced to store them as separate time series?

Answer (score 4):

It would be best to store them as separate time series, so you'd have one for the temperature, one for the current, one for the water height, one for the NaCl level, etc.  You can always query them back together.

Tags should be used primarily to classify data points of the same nature, for instance if you have multiple measurement points, then you'd have a tag that indicates which device collected the measurement.  That would allow you to get per-device time series, or to get an aggregate view of everything (either by summing, or averaging, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the fact, that tsuna is absolutely correct, i don't think, that its possible with OpenTSDB. The rows in which your data are saved, has one unique row key and multiple values - all of the same kind.

You can only put one value per timestamp (smallest time interval: 1 second) and per row key (metric name + hour timestamp + tagname). So you are simply not able to put values with the same timestamp or with different tags in one time series row. Or how would you like to differ the different measrement points (temp, current, waterheight etc.) without using tags?

Answer (score 1):

David,

The handling of data is described in:
http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/user_guide/writing.html

It is possible to force OpenTSDB into storing data this way (requires some tweaking and recompiling), you are basically correct: this is not the way you want to do this.

Judging by the measurements to be stored, I think I have actually worked in that field before.
There are 2 reasons to store the series as separate timeseries:

- You can only append **8** tags to a single datapoint, so you can have only ever have 6 measurements, assuming 1 tag for identification and 1 for location.
- Storing them as separate timeseries, you can take advantage of OpenTSDB's great internal data-parsing tools.

If you structure it like this:

```
1d.height t=timedate height rivername=name
```

You can instantly retrieve the the average height of the entire river.

Imagine what you could do with 2-dimensional bodies of water:

```
 2d.height t=timedate height type=lake name=IJsselmeer xcoord=xx ycoord=yy
```

There is a limit to the number of possible tag-values (16M). Depending on the resolution of what you want to store, you might want to divide your data into sectors and gridpoints. (in case you want to store the Atlantic in 1M resolution)